# Jquery pan svg image trouble

Tags: jquery, svg, zooming, pan

I have an interactive map. I'm trying to create a script to zoom and pan. The script is working as long as there isn't any image in the SVG element. When I put an image inside it, it doesn't work anymore because it selects the image and drag it. How can I disable this?

Here is the jquery code :

```
$(function(){
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    var originX;
    var originY;
    var dX = 0;
    var dY = 0;
    var clicking = false;

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       mouseX = e.pageX; 
       mouseY = e.pageY;
    });  

    $('#P1').on({
        mousemove: function(){
            if(clicking == true){
                dX = originX - mouseX;
                dY = originY - mouseY;
            }
        },
        mousedown: function(){
            clicking = true;
            originX = mouseX;
            originY = mouseY;
        },
        mouseup: function(){
            clicking = false;
            transX = $('#mapSVG').data('transx')+dX;
            transY = $('#mapSVG').data('transy')+dY;
            $('#mapSVG').data('transx',transX);
            $('#mapSVG').data('transy',transY);
            $('#mapSVG image').attr('transform','translate('+transX+','+transY+')');
            $('#mapSVG polygon').attr('transform','translate('+transX+','+transY+')');
        }
    }, '#mapSVG');
});
```

Here is the svg :

```
<svg id="mapSVG" height="800" width="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-transx="0" data-transy="0">';
    <image x="0" y="0" width="1600px" height="1600px" xlink:href="map.png" transform="translate(0,0"/>';
    <polygon points="703,600 704,593 711,588 722,581 739,574 753,571 769,576 771,583 774,586 785,585 790,595 791,607 781,610 780,615 782,624 769,631 751,636 739,640 737,635 721,640 712,633 706,624 704,613 " style="fill:lime; stroke:purple; stroke-width:1; opacity:0.3" transform="translate(0,0)"></polygon>
</svg>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the correct SVG would be

```
<svg id="mapSVG" height="800" width="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-transx="0" data-transy="0">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="1600px" height="1600px" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Provinces_of_Sicily_map.png" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
    <polygon id="P1" points="703,600 704,593 711,588 722,581 739,574 753,571 769,576 771,583 774,586 785,585 790,595 791,607 781,610 780,615 782,624 769,631 751,636 739,640 737,635 721,640 712,633 706,624 704,613 " style="fill:lime; stroke:purple; stroke-width:1; opacity:0.3" transform="translate(0,0)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

with corrected syntax and `<polygon>` with id "P1" (please edit the question accordingly if I'm right).

If `#P1` isn't the polygon, my answer is no valid anymore. Eventually I'll iterate it.

I've done an apparently working pen, although the user story isn't 100% clear to me: http://codepen.io/pioneerskies/pen/qEegbV where the the only problem I can see is a wrong event delegation: you are delegating events to `#P1` with target `#mapSVG`, but you can't delegate parent's event to one of its child nodes, because delegation will "watch" for events in descendants.

Official jQuery documentation about event delegation is at http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/